# TLS Errors after renewing Hyperledger Fabric Certificates BEFORE they expire

Tags: ssl

I have renewed the certificate, both enrollment and TLS, of a hyperledger network v2.4.9. The network has 3 Organizations. Each organization has:

- 1 Orderer
- 1 Peer
- 1 Root CA
- 1 TLS Root CA
- 1 Intermediate CA
- 1 TLS Intermediate CA

I've reenrolled all enrollment and TLS certificates using the `--csr.keyrequest.reusekey` option, replacing and restarting each container afterward. Everything seems to work, I can transact and If I didn't look at the logs, everything seems fine.

But in the logs, I find random TLS errors for Orderers and Peers:

```bash
ORDERER LOGS
ERRO [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> Server TLS handshake failed in 36.0ms with error read tcp [ORDERER_IP]:7050->212.102.40.218:48918: read: connection reset by peer server=Orderer remoteaddress=212.102.40.218:48918
ERRO [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> Server TLS handshake failed in 55.1ms with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=Orderer remoteaddress=35.203.211.250:61582
ERRO [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> Server TLS handshake failed in 18.587µs with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=Orderer remoteaddress=87.236.176.180:57533
ERRO [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> Server TLS handshake failed in 22.0 with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=Orderer remoteaddress=87.236.176.176:47297
ERRO [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> Server TLS handshake failed in 78.0ms with error EOF server=Orderer remoteaddress=87.236.176.231:51005
ERRO [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> Server TLS handshake failed in 78.2ms with error read tcp [ORDERER_IP]:7050->87.236.176.239:51593: read: connection reset by peer server=Orderer remoteaddress=87.236.176.239:51593
ERRO [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> Server TLS handshake failed in 78.3ms with error read tcp [ORDERER_IP]:7050->87.236.176.218:58221: read: connection reset by peer server=Orderer remoteaddress=87.236.176.218:58221
ERRO [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> Server TLS handshake failed in 82.0 with error tls: client requested unsupported application protocols ([hq h2c spdy/3 spdy/2 spdy/1 http/1.0 http/0.9]) server=Orderer remoteaddress=87.236.176.226:48859
ERRO [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> Server TLS handshake failed in 143.149µs with error tls: client offered only unsupported versions: [302 301] server=Orderer remoteaddress=87.236.176.227:48229
ERRO [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> Server TLS handshake failed in 78.2ms with error read tcp [ORDERER_IP]:7050->87.236.176.236:36537: read: connection reset by peer server=Orderer remoteaddress=87.236.176.236:36537
ERRO [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> Server TLS handshake failed in 20.0 with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=Orderer remoteaddress=34.208.218.63:64954
ERRO [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> Server TLS handshake failed in 22.0 with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=Orderer remoteaddress=34.208.218.63:52778

PEER LOGS
ERRO [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> Server TLS handshake failed in 19.311µs with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=PeerServer remoteaddress=162.142.125.213:34930
ERRO [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> Server TLS handshake failed in 1.012 with error read tcp 172.18.0.10:7051->162.142.125.213:38188: read: connection reset by peer server=PeerServer remoteaddress=162.142.125.213:38188
ERRO [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> Server TLS handshake failed in 1.0123 with error tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake server=PeerServer remoteaddress=162.142.125.213:47540
```

Am I missing something? Could I ignore these errors?